# Factoring Trigonometric Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

And so begins another day in my quest to pass Calculus I.

I have a question about factoring trigonometric expressions. I'm sorry I can't be more accurate than that, but I'm not sure of the names of the operations I need to perform.

I have a problem:

$$ -2(cos(x) – cos(2x)) = 0 $$

I divide both sides by -2:

$$cos(x) – cos(2x) = 0$$

And then transform the left hand side into a polynomial using the double angle formula:

$$1 + cos(x) – 2cos^2(x) = 0$$

However this is where I get stuck. According to Wolfram Alpha I am now supposed to factor the expression to get $-((cos(x) – 1)(1 + 2cos(x))) = 0$

Maybe I am missing something but I don't understand how to factor for that step. Could somebody explain it or link me to the names of the concepts I need to Google? Thanks.

Comment: Let $t=\cos(x)$. Could you factor $1+t-2t^2$?

Comment: Please be patient with me. I just refreshed myself on factoring by grouping. But it looks like for this situation I need two variables that multiplied together equal $-2cos^2x$ and added together equal $cosx$. Should I be approaching this from a different angle, like the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten to $1+\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)=0$ or, equivalently
$$
2(\cos(x))^2-\cos(x)-1=0
$$
Now, to make things easier to see, let $t=\cos(x)$. If you do, your equation now looks like
$$
2t^2-t-1=0
$$
which factors as
$$
(2t+1)(t-1) = 0
$$
This can only hold if either $2t=-1$ or $t=1$.
Now "unsubstitute" to get two possibilities:
$$
\begin{align}
2\cos(x) &= -1&\text{or}\\
\cos(x)&=1
\end{align}
$$
so, finally you need to find all $x$ for which $\cos(x)=1/2$ or $\cos(x)=1$. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I came to the same conclusion by substituting cosx with t but I didn't realize I could just substitute cosx back and get the right answer.